# Java EE WEB-INF Security

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I have a very basic login form which accepts username and password. When the data is submitted a controller class essentially authenticates the username and password, if the credentials are correct a user is then forwarded to a membersOnly.jsp which is located in the WEB-INF of the java EE project. Since content in the WEB-INF is only accessible by forwarding and not redirect I assume the only way someone can access this information is through the server-side forward.

My question is, how secure is this approach and should I use some other form of security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using some sort of custom-based authentication, but the [Java EE Standards](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbn) defines several authentication mechanisms:

- HTTP Basic authentication
- Form Based authentication
- HTTPS Client authentication

With Form-Based authentication you can still use your custom-made form, and delegate password validation to your Java EE Container. Almost every vendor offers credential validation against LDAP servers, database tables and other repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Most containers will handle authentication for you.

With Glassfish, for example, you can simply tell the container which database table contains users and passwords.

It will do the rest for you.

You can also let the container control access to different pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a bit too vague.